# foreach loop my code is as follows

Tags: codeigniter

```
$codes = test1,test2,test3;

$names = 1226261693assistenza-pc-1-1.jpeg,1226261693cobinhood.png,1226261693a.png;
foreach($codes as $k=>$v AND $names as $k2=>$v2){
echo '<TR><TD>$k</TD><TD>$v</TD><TD>$k2</TD><TD>$v2</TD></TR>;

}
```

This method didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This method didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

**Cause**

- **Missed quotes**     -

  ```
  $codes = test1,test2,test3;
  $names = 1226261693assistenza-pc-1-1.jpeg,1226261693cobinhood.png,1226261693a.png;
  ```

  Should be like this

  `$my_string_var = '<your string>';`  **OR**

  `$my_string_var = "<your string>";`
- **That is not valid** - `foreach($codes as $k=>$v AND $names as $k2=>$v2){ }`

`foreach` operates on only one array at a time.

**Solution**

If you have string variable like below,

```
$codes = 'test1,test2,test3';
$names = '1226261693assistenza-pc-1-1.jpeg,1226261693cobinhood.png,1226261693a.png';
```

Then make array and combine using [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), them and then loop it like below

```
$array = array_combine ( explode(',',$codes), explode(',', $names) );

/* 
   loop  array as array_key => array_value 
   $k = your array key
   $v = you array value
*/
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{

   echo "<TR><TD>$k</TD><TD>$v</TD></TR>";
}
```

Or else define array itself like below and loop it

```
$array = array(

            /* array_key  => array_value */
            'test1' => '1226261693assistenza-pc-1-1.jpeg',
            'test2' => '1226261693cobinhood.png'
       );
```

Comment: But 'test1,test2,test3'; i am fetching from database my code will  be like this $codes = $row['abc']; then how to take in array

Comment: @Anusha I didn't get you please explain